# How to get a list of connectivity ports on linux

Tags: ubuntu

How do I get a list of types of connectivity ports on linux

For example,
1 x HDMI
4 x USB
1x DVI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `dmidecode` package. Then run `dmidecode --type 8` as root. You'll see an output block for each connector your motherboard recognizes. For example, here's one my motherboards SATA ports:

```
Handle 0x0021, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: SATA1
    Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: SATA
```

You can also do something like

```
sudo dmidecode | grep "Port Type" | sort | uniq -c | cut -b 1-9,20-60
```

Example output:

```
  9          Audio Port
  3          Firewire (IEEE P1394)
  1          Keyboard Port
  1          Mouse Port
  1          Network Port
  4          Other
  8          SATA
  1          Serial Port 16550A Compatible
  6          USB
```

The 4 "Other" ports are internal fan connectors.

Comment: It has to be said that this will only list connectors on the motherboard, and only if the BIOS was correctly programmed to contain this information. Additionally, graphic card ports can be seen by `xrandr` (if X is running), and audio ports through `grep \\\[Jack\\\] /proc/asound/card*/codec#*`